# How to use form validation return values directly in html

Tags: forms, validation, ionic2, return-value, custom-validators

I'm trying to do form validation on an ionic 2 project and I'm having a problem using the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#component-template) method shown below:

```html
<div *ngIf="formErrors.spot" >
  {{ formErrors.spot }}
</div>
```

to directly show messages returned by the validation routine.

As a workaround, I'm using the method shown below, but I'd like to get rid of all of these constructs in the html

```html
<p *ngIf="signUpForm.controls.spot.hasError('not a whole number')">
   This is tooootally not a whole number
</p>
```

and instead use the angular method above that would replace all of that so that I don't have to maintain two sets of error messages (in the validator and the html itself.)

When I try to use the angular method, it seems like formErrors is undefined.

Here's the code

**HTML**

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="dark">
        <ion-title>NEW USER SIGNUP</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="login-content" padding>
    <div>
        <form [formGroup]="signUpForm">
            <ion-list inset>
                <ion-item [class.invalid]="!signUpForm.controls.spot.valid && (signUpForm.controls.spot.dirty)">
                    <ion-input placeholder="Parking Spot Number" formControlName="spot" [(ngModel)]="registerCredentials.spot"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <div *ngIf="!signUpForm.controls.spot.valid  && !signUpForm.controls.spot.pending && (signUpForm.controls.spot.dirty)">
                    <p *ngIf="signUpForm.controls.spot.hasError('too low')">
                        Seriously... waaaay too low.
                    </p>
                    <p *ngIf="signUpForm.controls.spot.hasError('too high')">
                        This is waaaay too high
                    </p>
                    <p *ngIf="signUpForm.controls.spot.hasError('not a number')">
                        This is tooootally not a number
                    </p>
                    <p *ngIf="signUpForm.controls.spot.hasError('not a whole number')">
                        This is tooootally not a whole number
                    </p>
                </div>
            </ion-list>
        </form>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**Here's the associated TS file**

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'
import { SpotValidator } from '../../validators/spotValidator2';
import * as moment from 'moment'

@Component({
  selector: 'page-signup',
  templateUrl: 'signup.html'
})
export class SignupPage2 {
  @ViewChild('signupSlider') signupSlider: any;
  signUpForm: FormGroup;

  private debugMode: boolean = true;
  registerCredentials = {
    spot: '',
  };

  constructor(
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.signUpForm = formBuilder.group({
      spot: ['', [SpotValidator.isValid]]
    });
  }
}
```

**And finally, the associated validator**

```js
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class SpotValidator {

    static isValid(control: FormControl): any {

        if(control.value == ""){
            return null
        }

        if(isNaN(control.value)){
            return {
                "not a number": true
            };
        }

        if(control.value % 1 !== 0){
            return {
                "not a whole number": true
            };
        }

        if (control.value > 260 ){ 
            return {
                "too high": true
            };
        }

        if (control.value < 31 ){
            return {
                "too low": true
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In short, how can I use this:

```html
<div *ngIf="formErrors.spot" >
  {{ formErrors.spot }}
</div>
```

to replace these:

```html
<p *ngIf="signUpForm.controls.spot.hasError('not a whole number')">
   This is tooootally not a whole number
</p>
```

in the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out. The Angular documentation doesn’t quite fit the model that I’d created (with help from a Josh Morony video) and I wanted to add the solution here to help the next guy. Specifically, the angular documentation uses a “change on update” event to trigger the reading of the values, but you can just use the returned value directly without that intermediate step. (Which was what where I was getting confused)

This is what I ended up with for the above example:

**HTML**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="dark">
        <ion-title>NEW USER SIGNUP</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="login-content" padding>
    <div>
        <form [formGroup]="signUpForm">
            <ion-list inset>
                <ion-item [class.invalid]="!signUpForm.controls.spot.valid && (signUpForm.controls.spot.dirty)">
                    <ion-input placeholder="Parking Spot Number" formControlName="spot" [(ngModel)]="registerCredentials.spot"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <div *ngIf="!signUpForm.controls.spot.valid  && !signUpForm.controls.spot.pending && (signUpForm.controls.spot.dirty)">
                    <p *ngIf="signUpForm.controls.spot.hasError('my_error_text')">
                        {{signUpForm.controls.spot.errors.my_error_text}}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </ion-list>
        </form>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

The TS file associated with the page is unchanged from above.

Finally, here is the validation page:
    import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

```
export class SpotValidator {

    static isValid(control: FormControl): any {

        if(control.value == ""){
            return null
        }

        if(isNaN(control.value)){
            return {
                "my_error_text": "not a number"
            };
        }

        if(control.value % 1 !== 0){
            return {
                "my_error_text": "not a whole number"
            };
        }

        if (control.value > 260 ){ 
            return {
                "my_error_text": "too high"
            };
        }

        if (control.value < 31 ){ //this allows for test parking spots during validation.
            return {
                "my_error_text": "too low"
            };
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```